# FInd the conditions for a bilinear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

to carry a straight line in z-plane onto the unit circle $|w|=1$

I could restrict this transformation to Moebius transformation which satisfies
$$ w=\frac{\alpha\, z+\beta}{\gamma\, z+ \delta}\qquad for \,\,every \,\, \alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma,\,\delta \in \mathbb C. 
$$
$$
where \qquad \alpha\gamma-\beta\delta \neq 0 \,\,,\,\,\gamma \ne 0, \,and \quad |\alpha|=|\gamma|
$$
Are there any conditions to add?

Comment: Orientation of the line perhaps? What is on the left of the line should map to what is on the left of the circle as you traverse it. You just need two points on the line and their ordering.

Comment: That is a good point, but do you think orientation can change the image ?

Comment: that depends on what you consider to be the domain.

Comment: the problem says a tranformation which carry a "straight line" onto the circle... so...

Comment: In your context the domain is probably $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}\cup \{ \infty \}$. But, in applications, we often think about mapping a half-plane. That said, for the whole complex plane, the orientation might not matter.